# Grails: Is it possible to query for the updated saved object from afterInsert() or afterUpdate()?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Say I have an model `Person`. My domain is making use of the GORM triggers as such:

```
def afterInsert() {
    someService.someMethod(this.id)
}

def afterUpdate() {
    someService.someMethod(this.id)
}
```

`SomeService` would  then look like this:

```
def someMethod(id) {
    // This query returns stale object
    def person = Person.findById(id)
}
```

Whenever `someMethod()` in `SomeService` gets called, the query does not return the updated object. Instead, it gets the old version/data.

My assumption is that by the time `afterUpdate()` is called, the changes have not been persisted to the DB yet. I've also tried `person.refresh()`, but obviously it runs into the same issue.
I've also tried `.save(flush:true)` in the original service where the object gets saved, but it still returns in the old data in the gorm trigger method.

So is there anyway for me to query for the `Person` object in such a way that it gets the very latest?
I'm a bit stumped on how this can be implemented.

Comment: This seems to imply that the stored entity is available via an argument passed into afterInsert/afterUpdate: http://guides.grails.org/gorm-event-listeners/guide/index.html.   Perhaps you could pass that into your service, rather than querying?

Comment: Have you tried just passing in the Person object rather than the id?  E.g., `someMethod(this)`.  I'm guessing your case is a simplification and that doesn't solve the underlying problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, the method requires the ID as it queries other tables with it as well.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, avoid database interaction from gorm hooks since you will run into problems when your app grows and you end up debugging a lot of StaleObject or OptimisticLocking -exceptions or other weird behaviour like you are seeing now.

Is better to change the underlying design here if possible and let for example a service to work as a entity persistor here if you need additional logic. Maybe you can use some event-driven mechanism here like activemq.

Injecting a service to a domain class is violation of design and is prevented by default in grails 3.x for performance reasons. Should be always avoided if possible. Active record will cause you problems if you keep pushing it to the edge like this.